# How do i add attributes to my images with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

i would like to know how i could add image attributes to the following code. I've added a teest function to see if the users browser supports webp image and if it doesn't it just shows a jpg image instead of webp but i want to add attributes and nothing i've done works.

```
function hasWebP() {
  var rv = $.Deferred();
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { rv.resolve(); };
  img.onerror = function() { rv.reject(); };
  img.src = '/images/home/dot.webp';
  return rv.promise();
}
hasWebP().then(function() {
    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src="images/home/IMG_4389.webp";
    img.id="picture";
    var foo = document.getElementById("myFace");
    foo.appendChild(img);
}, function() {
    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src="images/home/IMG_4389.png";
    img.id="picture2";
    var foo = document.getElementById("myFace");
    foo.appendChild(img);
});
```

Comment: Have you tested the img src urls? I tested with `img.src="/images/home/IMG_4389.png"` (note the / at the start of the src) and it appended the image to the DOM for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code to

```
function hasWebP() {
  var rv = $.Deferred();
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { rv.resolve(); };
  img.onerror = function() { rv.reject(); };
  img.src = '/images/home/dot.webp';
  return rv.promise();
}
hasWebP().then(function() {
    document.getElementById("picture").src="/images/home/IMG_4389.webp";
}, function() {
    document.getElementById("picture").src="/images/home/IMG_4389.png";
});
```

And added this to my html

```
<img src="" id="picture" draggable="false">
```